# iPhone: capturing back button event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, button, back

Greetings,

I have the following code for capturing the back button's event:

```
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doLogout:)]];
```

And here is my doLogout:

```
-(void) doLogout:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"hi");
}
```

Everything compiles and runs fine, and the back button text is changed to "Logout".

The only problem is that my doLogout function is never called!!!

What can I do? I've been stuck on this for an hour now... ;(

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Unreleated to your problem, but the `setBackBarButtonItem` method you've written will leak memory. You allocate a new `UIBarButtonItem` but never release it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official doc:

When this item is the back item of the navigation bar—when it is the next item below the top item—it may be represented as a back button on the navigation bar. Use this property to specify the back button. **The target and action of the back bar button item you set should be nil.** The default value is a bar button item displaying the navigation item’s title.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to catch "back button event" why no just just try overriding `UIViewController viewDidUnload`?

Comment: He may want some special logic when an user explicitly presses the back button, not when a view disappears. A view could disappear when you push a view controller

Comment: @Hisoka when you push a viewController, `viewDidUnload` is not called. (unless you have memory warnings, but that's another topic) View is unloaded only when removed from memory, which normally happens when leaving (back button). Another solution could be using the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `backBarButtonItem` on the top view controller, what you could do is set the `leftBarButtonItem` on the child view controller.  This can be any arbitrary bar button item and all action messages should be delivered as normal. Because this takes place of the back button, you have to make sure you manually pop the child controller in one of the action methods.